# Pulling HTML from MySQL, Strange Encoding issue upon echoing data?

Tags: php, mysql, encoding

### MORE NEW INFO

Found another interesting thing. In my find email method (gathers email addresses for final mysql call), the method looks like:

```
protected function setAllByEmail($email) {
    $data = array( 'names' => array(), 'phones' => array(), 'emails' => array(), 'orders' => array(), 'requestIDs' => array() );
    $this->load->model('cookies/vwrequesthistory');
    $araCookies = $this->vwrequesthistory->getByEmail($email);
    if (count($araCookies) !=0) {
    // filter and run 2 more models against 2 more db's for email addys
}
```

If I put ANY OF MY NEW CODE  **OR** `return $data` after the first line of the method, I start getting the weird encoding issue, but as long as i leave that old method alone (which uses models i'm trying to get rid of!) it works just fine with no weird ISO encoding!

### Latest Update <sub>Final found a small difference!</sub>

After hours of head pounding, I had begun moving in reverse. A little backdrop on how this data is gathered. The final result (**containing the Email HTMLs I need to show in browser**) is queryed after 3 initial queries which gather data for the final query.  I have 3 php methods that call these initial queries using CI's `load->database->` method. Then I call the final query. In my OLD way of using these functions, eached reached out to an independent model for that DB and grabbed what was needed, then filtered the return. In my NEW methods, each function uses CI's AR to call the DB's directly then filter the results. Both methods do the same work, just in different ways. In my NEW PROBLEM, I've found that if i call my new init get phone & get order# methods with my OLD get email method, everything is fine. But as soon as I try to use my new get EMAIL method, is when i get the weird encoding. However the data return seems to be the EXACT same from either!

I've run a few dif test including assigning the new method and immediately returning false data and still get the same issue. I even tried assigning the new method and making the method completely blank, same issue! I tried moving the new methodology into the old method, same issue! It seem to ONLY WORK with the old method which was poorly written as a rough draft!

> DATA Returns

```
     OLD
array(5) {
  ["names"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "Anon"
    [1]=>
    string(12) "Anon Anon"
  }
  ["phones"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "5555555555"
  }
  ["emails"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(23) "Anon@gmail.com"
  }
  ["orders"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "987654"
  }
  ["requestIDs"]=>
  &array(0) {
  }
}

NEW
array(5) {
  ["names"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "Anon"
    [1]=>
    string(12) "Anon Anon"
  }
  ["phones"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "5555555555"
  }
  ["emails"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(23) "Anon@gmail.com"
  }
  ["orders"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "987654"
  }
  ["requestIDs"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

### <strike>Latest Update</strike>

- MySQL DB set to UTF-8
- Codeigniter all set to UTF-8
- CI is even set to push UTF-8 encoding to header
- The sql call is now hand written and i've used both "SETCHAR" and "mysql_set_charset" to try and change the result (still on php 4.? here)
- Master View has UTF-8 in <head>
- The ajax call is set to use only UTF-8
- The layout of load is as follows (for the moment):

  masterView->usePHPinBodyToLoadEmailListView->UseAjaxToGetDataToPopulateView

### Still having the same old issue

So I've looked through a few dozen answers, googled, and tried everything I know, including header change, access change, file encoding change; everything. At the end of the day, here is a list of my tools:

Komodo Edit / Codeigniter / MySQL / jQuery.Ajax Method / Google Chrome & FireFox

**My Issue**: Space being replaced with Â&nbsp and other ISO-8859-1 type oddities

**What I've observed**: (Probably key to problem here)

```
The Data is sent to jQuery.getJSON as `echo(json_encode($data));`
The HTML seemed to parse just fine to the web page in original config, 
    however the data layout was undesirable as it interfered with other pulls

The Data itself was originally arranged as follows:
    array(i) [
        0 => array(i) [
            'emailID' => 'string',
            'emailType' => 'string',
            'emailHTML' => 'string', <---- the html pulled!!!
        ],
        1 => [
            'emailID' => 'string',
            'emailType' => 'string',
            'emailHTML' => 'string', <---- the html pulled!!!
        ],
        'initData' => array(i) [ ... ]
    ]

The New Data Layout: (When the error mentioned began to occur)
    array(i) [
        'initID' => 'string',
        'initEmailAddy' => 'string',
        'initPhone' => 'string',
        'emailPull' => array(i) [
            0 => array(i) [
                'emailID' => 'string',
                'emailType' => 'string',
                'emailHTML' => 'string' <---- the html pulled!!!
            ]
            1 => array(i) [
                'emailID' => 'string',
                'emailType' => 'string',
                'emailHTML' => 'string' <---- the html pulled!!!
            ]
            2 => array(i) [ ... ]
        ]
    ]
```

Without changing my data layout, is it possible to fix my issue, and if so, why?

### Update!

Changed back to original Data struct and still having new issue! Now I'm really lost. I reset everything to 0, literally. New folder, new files, copied and pasted code in text editor minding my encoding the whole time. EVERYTHING IS SET TO UTF-8 including the database, but I'm still getting the same ISO result!? HTML has the included the `<meta>` tag, CI has charset set, modified header lib to force UTF-8 to header. It seems like I've done everything imaginable, everything worked fine 2 days ago! I really honestly can't find the problem now.

When pulling the data using PHP on the HTML page, it displays just fine. When loaded via controller, with PHP on page, works just fine, when loaded into master page via AJAX, it suddenly breaks. I've set the encoding on my calls, still nothing. Also tried loading it via PHP instead of ajax and still broken. But 2 days ago, inside this same layout (controller->masterpage->loadContent) it worked just fine. Only thing I've changed since then **was the way I arrange the data sent to the `getJSON` call.**

Comment: Anytime you EVER see `Â` coming out in front of where you expect non-ascii chars to be, you've got a charset encoding issue. Your **ENTIRE** rendering pipeline MUST use the same charset throughout, or have the appropriate translation logic. e.g `browser -> server -> php -> mysql -> table -> mysql -> php -> browser`. each of those stages must be configured identically.

Comment: Along with what Marc B said, take a look at the results of the json encoding and see if it's changing data / encoding. You can get your json from the console and look at it here : http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/ .

Comment: @MarcB Been there done that, still same issue ...

Comment: @Shawn Yes, my encoding is working just fine.

Comment: Can you post the full ajax request which is returning corrupted data?  (request + response headers, data).

Comment: @SpYk3HH It may be notable that if the data was entered incorrectly initially you need to transfer it *incorrectly* for it to display correctly. That is, if your tables were initially *not* utf8 encoded and you changed the encoding lazily, it won't work. You need to change them back to the non-utf8 encoding and re-convert them using an intermediate BLOB/binary conversation. (See the warning at the bottom of http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/alter-table.html)